# AVR self-reset / hardware reset from own own pin

Tags: avr, reset

Can I use a capacitor to perform a self-reset / hardware reset of an AVR microcontroller?

The capacitor would be driven low by a pin on the microcontroller.
Arduino uses this mechanism for programming via USB to UART bridges.

I would like the DTR pin to come from an internal pin, discharge the cap and pull the RESET to low.

[image]

Comment: Normally you’d use the watchdog to force a reset. Much easier than using a capacitor

Comment: yes, that is a pure software reset. It doesn't completely reset the state of the MCU (registers, ram, etc.).

Comment: Err no. It performs a hardware reset. Refer to the datasheet. Note that with an external reset, ram doesn’t get reset and only specific registers get initialised. A software reset is a jump to the start address. Very different to a watchdog reset.

Comment: Why would you need a capacitor for that? And why you need hardware reset with a GPIO pin, if you can trigger a hardware reset via software (e.g. via watchdog)?

Comment: You could probably just connect a GPIO to the reset pin. Without configuration, it will be configured as input (high-Z) and the pullup will keep RESET high. To trigger a reset, the GPIO will have to become an output, but once the reset is done, the GPIO will change back to be an input (data direction registers get changed on reset).

Comment: DTR =0, capacitor charged, DTR=1, double voltage applied to input. Damage may be caused.

Comment: Very nice observations, thank you all.
Indeed, for AtMega328p, the watchdog performs a HW reset! - didn't know that.
Kartman, please post an answer so I can approve it.

Answer (score 2):

Coming back to this 9M later, it seems there is an [official Microchip support answer](https://microchipsupport.force.com/s/article/Software-Reset):

If you want to perform a software reset of your AVR you should use the internal Watchdog. Simply enable it and let it time out. When the Watchdog triggers it resets the program counter back to 0, clears all the registers and performs all the other tasks. This operation gives the same result as pulling the RESET line low.

You should **not** try to:

- Use another pin of the AVR to pull the external RESET line. The pins of the AVR are tristated halfway through the minimum reset time, this releases the RESET line and hence nothing happens.
- Jump to program location 0. Jumping to program location 0 does not clear all the registers and hence you do not have a "clean" reset.

Example Code (GCC) Resetting the AVR every 30mS:

```cpp
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>

int main(void)
{
    wdt_enable(WDTO_30MS);
    while(1) {};
}
```

I'm still searching for a hardware alternative, since I think the Watchdog will still consume some amount of power which I'd rather save, even if it's microamps.

Comment: @user263983: since the RESET pin is capable of up to 13V and the VCC is 3V3 or 5V, wouldn't this be ok at least for the RESET pin? What do you think about the DTR pin?

Comment: But if the WDT is enabled only when you want to do a reset, what difference it makes if it consumes few microamps for 30ms? You will spend much more current running the AVR in while loop for the 30ms before WDT resets it, and that is avoidable. And the comment why not use the GPIO to reset itself is contradictory. If nothing happens when pulse is too short, how come the GPIO pin can generate a reset to tristate GPIO to begin with to end up with too short pulse? And surely external components can be used to extend the pulse. What is it you are trying to do or achieve?

Comment: Also, how about never putting the DTR line to HIGH? (only tri-state by default + LOW to actually reset?)

Comment: @Justme I was under the false impression the watchdog is toggled via fusebits. Since it is software-controlled this is the best approach!

Comment: @Justme: " If nothing happens when pulse is too short, how come the GPIO pin can generate a reset to tristate GPIO to begin with to end up with too short pulse? " - the capacitor would hold the line low for the RESET to happen.

Comment: Yes but if you say nothing happens, how come the GPIO got tristated, so it must have reacted to the reset pulse already, so something already happened instead of nothing. Either something happens, or not.

Comment: In the support answer from Microchip, with no additional circuitry (no capacitor), connecting a GPIO pin to RESET will not work because the pin would get tristated before the reset occurs. This StackExchange thread refers to a design with a cap which would hold RESET low for the required amount of time.

Comment: That is hilarious. The reset must occur if the GPIO pin goes to tristate, as if the reset did not occur, it would not get tristated. Shows how much you can trust vendor forums for official support. If you gave the AVR model number you could check the data sheet what is true and what is not.